# Script or tool to get the IP address of a remote host

Tags: networking, bash, script

I want to set an environment variable with the IP address of a given remote host. This is the solution I've arrived to:

```
export IP=`curl http://network-tools.com/default.asp?host=www.example.com | 
       grep -oE '<br>[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' | 
       cut -c5-`
```

It works fine but I have a few questions:

1. Is there is a simple tool to obtain the same result?  I need it to work through a proxy that limits the host names, that's why I use the network-tools page.
2. How can I make it a function of the host name? someting like getIP(hostname)

Comment: #3 is a very different question from the other two, and as it currently stands, extremely broad. I doubt that can even be answered in a good way as it is written now.

Answer (score 5):

Try something like

```
export IP=`( dig ${HOSTNAME} A +short | tail -n1; \
             dig ${HOSTNAME} AAAA +short | tail -n1 ) \
           | head -n1`
```

This will give you:

- For a host with at least one IPv4 address, (one of) the IPv4 address
- For a host with no IPv4 addresses but with at least one IPv6 address, (one of) the IPv6 address
- For a host with no (IPv4 or IPv6) address at all in DNS, or if there is a resolver failure, an empty value

If you don't need IPv4 or IPv6 capability (your question seems to indicate you are mostly interested in the IPv4 address), just remove that `dig` command (`A` is IPv4, `AAAA` is IPv6). So, if you are only interested in IPv4 addresses:

```
export IP=`dig ${HOSTNAME} A +short | tail -n1`
```

The `tail -n1` ensures that you get an IP address (in the case of `CNAME`, and possibly other record types, `dig` outputs the referenced canonical name on the first line). The `head -n1` ensures that you only get a single address by returning only the first line of the remaining output (unnecessary in the case of only one address family, since `tail` will return only one address). Since DNS records are normally served in a round-robin fashion, there is no guarantee which exact address will be returned for multiple-address hosts.

I'm not too familiar with writing bash functions, but it should be relatively easy to turn this into a function.

Comment: Most stacks prefer IPv6, if available; consequently, you probably want `tail -n 1` at the top level, as well, if you want to mirror the host's resolve order.  Then again, this whole approach also doesn't respect NIS, or `/etc/hosts`, or `nsswitch.conf`, and yet I use it regularly nonetheless on machines where `resolveip -s` isn't necessarily available, so perhaps I'm being a bit too pedantic.  ;)

Comment: @BMDan The snippet in the question doesn't even support IPv6, which is (likely; it's been about two years now) why I went with this particular ordering.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your meaning.  The snippet you provided explicitly queries both A and AAAA, so it's IPv6-aware.  I agree insofar as your assertion that you share functionality with the original, but I think that the goal is to *improve* on what was in the question, not merely to parrot its shortcomings.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

- `host www.example.com`
- `nslookup www.example.com`
- `dig www.example.com`

Depending on how much additional information you want, chose the appropriate candidate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tryed all the three but they doen't seem to work (in my context). For example `host` returns the message  `host www.example.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`. I have also created the file etc/resolv.conf both with the ip of dns server obtained with the command `ipconfig /all` and with the ip of googles's public dns 8.8.8.8 without success. I fear the problem comes from some kind of limitation placed by my network's security.

Comment: That looks like a problem with DNS resolution on your machine. The `dig` command may come in handy here, permitting to specify the nameserver to use, e.g. `dig @ns.example.com www.example.com` would use `ns.example.com` as name server (you could also specify an IP here). `nslookup` also permits this (please check with `man nslookup` for details). `host` would have been especially nice for you as it returns only the IP (without additional information to filter out) -- but it requires DNS resolution to work on the host directly.